# Angular Material 2 dialog appears darker

Tags: angular2-directives, angular-material2

I'm a new user to Angular 2 and Angular Material 2, I try to generate a dialog following some tutorials but when show dialog this appear darker.

[image]

Any help me is really helpful.

Comment: A few possibilities: you need to provide a core theme for angular material components as descripted here: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming. Also, is it possible you set your dialog to have a transparent background? Because the dark background overlay that naturally appears behind the dialog would make your transparent background appear even darker.

Comment: @John Thanks, I not added correctly the core theme on my global style.

Answer (score 0):

Hoisted from the comments: the problem was that there wasn't a core theme for angular material components as descripted [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming).